# Why google chrome place my page at the very center of the window (CSS&HTML issue)?

Tags: php, css, html

My simple website with a header, navigation menu, footer and few sections runs fine in all browsers except google chrome. When I launch it in Chrome, it centers the page, like squeezing at the very middle of the browser page.

Look it [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/100402704740320621129/albums/6043311620440614353/6043311629405355762?pid=6043311629405355762&oid=100402704740320621129)

[image]

My code:
.PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Fatah's Homepage</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">

    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripting.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>


    <header id="top_header" >
        <h1>Welcome to my world!</h1>
    </header>

    <nav id="top_menu">
        <ul>
            <li>HOME</li>
            <li>WHO I'M</li>
            <li>GALLERY</li>
            <li>MY DIARY</li>
            <li>BLOG</li>    
        <ul>
    </nav>

<div id="new_div">
<section id="main_section">
<article>


<header>
<hgroup>
    <h1>Title of Article 1</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle of the article 1</h2>
</hgroup>
</header>

<p>This is the first best article ever</p>
<footer>
-Written by Jabir
</footer>
</article>


<article>


<header>
<hgroup>
    <h1>Title of Article 2</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle of the article 2</h2>
</hgroup>
</header>

<p>This is the second best article ever</p>
<footer>
-Written by Jabir
</footer>
</article>
</section>
</div>

<aside id="side_news">
<h4>Fatah's update</h4>
Fatah became very stupid!
</aside>

<footer id="the_footer">
Developed by Jabir Al Fatah 2014
</footer>

</div>

</body>





</html>
```

.CSS:

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;

}
h1{
font:bold 20px Tahoma;

}
h2{
font:bold 14px Tahoma;

}
header,section,footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup{
display:block;
}
body{
width:100%;
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
}
#wrapper{
max-width:1000px;
margin:20px auto;
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient:vertical;
-webkit-box-flex:1;

}
#top_header{
background:yellow;
border:3px solid black;
padding:20px;
}
#top_menu{
border:red;
background:blue;
color:white;
}
#top_menu li{
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
padding:5px;
font:bold 14px Tahoma;
}
#new_div{
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
}
#main_section{

border:1px solid blue;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
margin:20px;
padding:20px;
}

#side_news{
border:1px solid red;    
width:220px;     
margin:20px 0px;
padding:30px;
background:blue;
}

#the_footer{
text-align:center;
padding:20px;
border-top: 2px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the **display:-webkit-box;** in body ....

```
body{
width:100%;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
margin:20px auto;
```

You set the width margin to auto, normally it only centers when a width is set but well it does it for you, replace:

```
margin: 20px auto;
```

with

```
margin: 20px 0px;
```

or something like that

Comment: perfect. your answer will be accepted in a few moments.

Comment: there is a very tiny problem remaining still now, and that is every other browser, it doesn't keep margin from the left. I want it to run like Google chrome in all other browser too. Look my picture (https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/100402704740320621129/albums/6043320471949964369/6043320475934989090?pid=6043320475934989090&oid=100402704740320621129) how it launches in IE.

Comment: @JabirALFatah keep everything as before and just remove display:-webkit-box; that will solve the issue...

Comment: You can still set a margin to the left, so margin: 20px 10px; is also fine, just not auto :)